# Recommendations to treat 4f electrons (valence) of Yb3+ in magnetic systems in VASP

Tags: vasp, pseudopotentials, lanthanide

**I need help with:** I would like to know what is the most common approach to treat valence 4f electrons of lanthanides (3+ charge) in VASP that circumvents the calculation problems shown below. (or more recommendations)

**System**: I am having trouble with SCF calculations of a system that contains $\ce{2Yb^{3+}}$ as dopants when including 4f electrons of Yb.

**Setup**: I am using the parameters below in the `INCAR` file:

```
NWRITE = 2          
ISTART = 0  
ICHARG = 2    
LORBIT = 11
LPLANE = .FALSE. 
NPAR = 4   
PREC  = Accurate  (Precision level)  
LREAL = AUTO  (Projection operators: automatic) 
ALGO  = N         (Elect. algorithm: 38/48)  
ENCUT = 500 eV

!GGA + U correction for Yb ion 
LDAU = .TRUE. 
LDAUTYPE = 2  
LDAUL = -1 -1 -1 3 
LDAUU = 0 0 0 7 
EDIFF  = 1.0e-05  
EDIFFG = -1.0e-01      
NBLOCK = 1       
IBRION = -1 
NSW    = 0  
ISYM   = 0    
ISMEAR = 0   
SIGMA  = 0.01  
POTIM  = 0.90 
LWAVE = .TRUE. 
LCHARG = .TRUE.
!Magnetisation   
ISPIN  = 2  
LMAXMIX = 6 ! FM ORDER 
MAGMOM = 27*0 24*0 81*0 1.0 1.0 
NUPDOWN = 2

!Mixer  
AMIX     = 0.2 
BMIX     = 0.00001 
AMIX_MAG = 0.8 
BMIX_MAG = 0.00001
```

Also, I have varied several of them `ENCUT`, `AMIX` and `BMIX` as well as the U correction from 3 to 7. Have also tried different electronic algorithms to no avail.

This is a 3x3x3 supercell so I am testing runs only on the Gamma point and also with automatic Gamma 2 2 2 grid.
I have tried HSE0 functional as well and the same problem persists.

**Errors**: Using `ALGO=N` I can get this error:

```
Error EDDDAV: Call to ZHEGV failed. Returncode =   7 1   8
and some other trials the energies keep decreasing indefinitely to really big negative numbers: 
free energy    TOTEN  =      -131.40843111 eV 
free energy    TOTEN  =      -120.45157042 eV  
free energy    TOTEN  =      -103.28925863 eV  
free energy    TOTEN  =    -12481.39444222 eV 
free energy    TOTEN  = -67096650.34128196 eV 
free energy    TOTEN  = ****************** eV 
free energy    TOTEN  = ****************** eV
```

**Workarounds?**: I have found papers where a "\Delta SCF" approach is used to move one 4f electron to 5d orbital and reach desired orbital occupancy ($\ce{Yb^{3+}}$) but to know which band's occupation one needs to modify, a previously converged solution (probably without spin polarization: ISPIN=1) is needed which is not possible in my case due to charge unbalance.

**Other resources:** Similar issues have been found in other systems with lanthanides and specifically with $\ce{Yb^{3+}}$: See post [here](https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18253).
and also [here](https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14808&p=14808&hilit=4f+electrons#p14808).

**Note:** When turning off spin polarization and using Yb_3 (valence : 5p6 6s2 5d1) PAW pseudopotential with frozen f electrons the calculations converge just fine.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future !!! I made some edits to improve the formatting. Can you please look through them and continue to fix things (for example using ChemJax for the chemical formulas, and removing the `</br>` statements from your code, and using hyperlinks rather than raw URLs?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I have fixed formatting things as you recommended.

Comment: Also following this link to see if someone can find a solution to this
[VASP USER FORUM(https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=18253&sid=7bbab1c76c01ef3bc8ae204dd8e0f163)

Comment: I am also working on Yb3+ compound using VASP. There is an article published in 2010(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0966979510003730), and the authors also included 4f orbitals in Yb3+ in their calculation. The same authors used VASP and they seemed successfully converged the electron SCF part. Maybe you want to ask the authors regarding your Yb3+ issues? Best Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 6):

There is a [discussion](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Available_PAW_potentials#f_elements) on this limitation on VASP page. Maybe the approach of a frozen f valence PAW pseudopotential could help you. Although magnetic properties might not be as well represented.
I'm quantum espresso user and when their PAW potentials show problems (not so rare) I go to a norm-conserving solution like `pseudodojo` library, if you can do this in VASP i think it may help.
Also about the charge treatment, in QuantumESPRESSO in many cases I just implement a total charge on the supercell instead of specific atom as I think you're doing. If you have a dopant scf will usually bring charge localization towards the dopant in the end without need to explicitly set it in the atom, it may help convergence too.

Comment: Thank you for this information @Rogério
1) For my system, I need those f electrons in the valence space so using frozen f valence PAW would defeat the purpose as you mention. 
2) To your second point, I don't think it is easy to use `pseudodojo` pseudop in VASP (format of POTCAR is too different than the available formats at `pseudodojo`) 
3) For the charge, I would also set the system charge instead of local charges in cases of need of charge compensation. 
I haven't found a solution to this yet, that is why I am not accepting your answer yet. But thank you for your insights.